# How can i Integrate Sonarqube for the Reactjs application via azure devops pipeline

Tags: reactjs, azure, sonarqube, devops

i am trying to integrate Sonar qube with azure pipleine for my Reactjs application,
i my azure pipelines i have added task

```
      - task: SonarQubePrepare@4
        displayName: 'Prepare SonarQube analysis'
        inputs:
          SonarQube: 'ServiceConnection'
          scannerMode: 'CLI'
          configMode: 'manual'
          cliProjectKey: 'ServicePortal'
          cliProjectName: 'ServicePortal'
          cliSources: '.'
          extraProperties: |
            sonar.host.url=https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/
            sonar.login=$(SonarToken)
```

where i have given my Token and url and created a Sonar.project.properties file provided the key and value and version and source.

but after running the pipeline . Sonar Analysis is success but SonarPublish is issuing problem

```
 - task: SonarQubePublish@5
   inputs:
     pollingTimeoutSec: '300'
```

what am i doing wrong here?

how to write Sonar.project property file and azure task as well?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing [SonarQubeAnalyze](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/sonar-qube-analyze-v5?view=azure-pipelines) which has to come before `SonarQubePublish`

```
- task: SonarQubeAnalyze@5
  inputs: # none
```

Also, the sonar host and authentication information would already be part of your `ServiceConnection`, so I dont think you need to specify it in the `extraProperties`.

Comment: I tired with that Task.but its showing me like yours is a community edition. this task can be used in Developer Edition.

Comment: I am currently using this task with Community Edition just fine. Perhaps you are trying to use some Developer edition features like multiple branches or pull request analysis ?

Comment: @sharma Were you able to run it successfuly?